# Angular | How to set value of a signal based on the value of another signal?

Tags: angular

I have two signals:

```
isFoo = this.store.selectSignal(abcd);  
isBar = signal(false);
```

`isBar` gets updated based on some other user interactions in the component. If the value of `isFoo` is true, `isBar` should always be false.

In the component's constructor, I am using an effect to handle that like so:

```
        effect(() => {
            if (this.Foo())
                this.isBar.set(false)
        },
        {allowSignalWrites: true})
```

Is there any other way to update the signal without having to use `{allowSignalWrites: true}` ? According to the documentation, that config option should be sparingly used. However, I am not sure how else to handle this scenario.

Comment: How about `isBaz = computed(() => this.isFoo() ? true : this.isBar())`? Let `isBar` change as is.

Comment: I ended up creating a third signal as suggested. Not sure which one of the two is a better approach though. Under what scenarios should we be using the `allowSignalWrites: true` config option?

Comment: there's not a consensus. I'm personally averse - feels too heavy a hammer to force an update within the same "tick", but smarter minds than me are happily using it eg [ngx-signal-state](https://github.com/simplifiedcourses/ngx-signal-state).